# plone single sign on authentication

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, plone

i would like to use user authentication with google single sign on/authentication systems for one of Content management site using plone.

Please some one help me out how to do and the best way to complete it.

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.nathanvangheem.com/posts/2017/02/21/using-authomatic-in-plone.html

Comment: For Plone support, please post questions at https://community.plone.org